# Criar Dockerfile para Zend Expressive

Tags: zend, docker, php-7

Olá pessoal estou com um dificuldade para rodar o zend expressive com o docker. Tenho outros projetos que funcionam perfeitamente com o docker mas quando eu vou tentar desenvolver com o zend expressive, não consigo, dá erro dizendo que não consegue encontrar o arquivo vendor/autoload.php, sendo que o mesmo está lá.. já tentei de várias manerias mas não tem jeito, se eu entro pelo MAMP, funcona direitinho, mas pelo docker não. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Segue abaixo o Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN apt-get update

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# install GD
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# install json
RUN docker-php-ext-install json
```

Ah, para eu criar a imagem do php estou usando "docker build -t projeto/php7 . "

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço..

Comment: Você entrou no container em execução para checar o arquivo em seu caminho absoluto e suas permissões?

Comment: Como assim? não entendi.. o que eu sei é que tem as permissões corretas e que está apontando para a pasta public do projeto, isso está certo até porque está dando o erro do autoload.php, que é este:

Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11

Comment: Como você sabe que o arquivo está acessível dentro do container? Você precisaria entrar nele pra ter certeza, entende? Tem que executá-lo em modo detached (-d) e depois entrar nele pra acessar seu conteúdo com o exec -it.

Comment: Como você sabe que o arquivo está acessível dentro do container? Você precisaria entrar nele pra ter certeza, entende? Tem que executá-lo em modo detached (-d) e depois entrar nele pra acessar seu conteúdo com o exec -it.

Comment: Ta.. eu acesso o container e tenho que acessar a pasta aonde ele tá? como posso fazer isso? OBS: eu sei como acessar o bash, mas não sei como acessar ver o arquivo

Comment: Como está reclamando do arquivo /var/www/html/index.php, depois de entrar no container, roda um "ls -l /var/www/html/index.php".

Comment: Olha, eu acho que ja descobri o que está acontecendo, só não sei como resolver.. o Zend Expressive tem uma estrutura de pastas assim: 
- config
- src
- public
- vendor
- templates
e eu configurei o docker-compose.yml para acessar a pasta public por padrão e por causa disso a pasta vendor e as outras não estão sendo "assistidas" pelo container.. só que se eu iniciar o container na raiz e acessar localhost/public, da erro de rota no zend expressive. Sabe como me ajudar? se eu não expliquei direito me avisa..

Comment: Como está teu docker-compose? Como você configurou esse diretório public? Não tem como informar todos os diretórios que precisam ser acessados nele? Se você configurou como volumes, teria que informar todos.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada no meu github esta em [https://github.com/AlexandroZaleski/zend-expressive] ali tu vai ver toda a estrutura e os arquivos do docker.. um colega meu me disse que eu precisava instalar o composer no container, to tentando mas ainda não consegui.. e tbm não sei se vai resolver.. mas to atirando para todos os lados kkk. obrigado pela força

Comment: Pessoal, eu consegui fazer funcionar mas usando o servidor interno do php com esta linha no meu docker-compose: command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public. Pelo apache  ainda não consigo, então estou usando assim por enquanto.. Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está uma configuração de PHP e Apache para rodar a aplicação com Zend Expressive:
https://gist.github.com/argentinaluiz/6ab98dc03c204a59a5ea6ee018550ee5

;)

Comment: Obrigado Luiz ;)